# Issue related to system function

Tags: c++, signals

In the below code, when system function get executed (in Linux and compiled with g++), it will send the `SIGCHLD` signal to process (from which it is called) which doesn't happen in Solaris code. I mean, if I run the same code in Solaris, the system function doesn't send any signal to the process from which it is called. As a result, my process in Linux hangs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <signal.h>

void sigHandler(int sgnNbr)
{
    cout <<"Signal " << sgnNbr << "caught" << endl;
    system("echo $HOSTNAME");
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGCHLD,sigHandler);
    system("echo $HOSTNAME");
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why does the process hang in the above case?
2. why does the system function not send any signal in Solaris?

... and my last question, which is related to my real application:

Actually, in my real application (in which single signal handler is there for some four signals), some other process sending the SIGABRT signal to my process and in signal handler I am killing the one process using system function as a result it got hanged(which is similar to the above scenario). Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: If you read the [`signal(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) manual page, you will see the `system` is not among the "safe" functions to call inside a signal handler.

Comment: Also, I don't know about Solaris today, but it used to handle `SIGCHLD` and `SIGCLD` differently, and maybe `system` raises the the `SIGCLD` signal instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/system.html:

> The system() function shall ignore the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals, and shall block the SIGCHLD signal, while waiting for the command to terminate.

Solaris is correct; Linux is incorrect.

The most likely reason that your program is hanging is that it is not safe to call `system` within a signal handler.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04 for the list of async-signal-safe functions.

To kill another process, you can use [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/kill.html), which is async-signal-safe.

Comment: the point here is , i am using system command to kill the process with its PID .So is there any way to kill the process or some other way to handle sytem command in signal handler

Comment: Can u please let me know how can i check why the SIGCHLD was not blocked in case of linux

Comment: @facebook-100001358991487 you should use `kill` directly (`kill` is a function in `<signal.h>`).  About the issue on Linux, http://lists.uclibc.org/pipermail/uclibc/2012-January/046250.html might be relevant (you mentioned Solaris, so you might be on Sparc).